# why is the resulting out put of console.log(Object +1) is like this?

Tags: javascript, concatenation, operator-overloading, addition

why is the out put of

```js
console.log(Object +1)
```

is

```
function Object() {
    [native code]
}1
```

i tried it and expext a numeric value as the + description :

- If one side is a string, the other operand is also converted to a string and they are concatenated.
- If they are both BigInts, BigInt addition is performed. If one side is a BigInt but the other is not, a TypeError is thrown.
- Otherwise, both sides are converted to numbers, and numeric addition is performed.

Comment: You left out the step of converting the operands to their primitive value. The primitive value of a function is a string, not a number. So the first bullet applies.

Comment: Objects are first converted to a primitive by calling their [@@toPrimitive]() (with "number" as hint), valueOf(), and toString() methods, in that order. The resulting primitive is then converted to a number. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_coercion)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, JS calls `Object`'s `toPrimitive` method, which gives the following string:

```
function Object() {
    [native code]
}
```

In the next step, JS converts `1`(number) into the `"1"`(string), as the first operand is a string, after that it's just a concatenation of two strings that results in:

```
function Object() {
    [native code]
}1
```

Here is the [link](https://javascript.info/object-toprimitive) for a detailed explanation.